# Confused about how to find the value of $(1+i)^{12}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am learning de Moivre’s theorem, which states that

> (cos $\theta +i$ sin $\theta)^n =$ cos $n\theta + i$ sin $n\theta$

In my book, there is this question: $(1+i)^{12}$

And the book provides the following solution:

$(1+i)^{12}$

$=(\sqrt{2})^{12}\big(\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+i \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\big)^{12}$

$=64\big($ cos $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4} \color {red}-i$ sin $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4}\big)^{12}$

$=64 ($cos $3\pi+ i$ sin $3\pi\big)$

$=64 ($cos $\pi+i$ sin $\pi)$

$=-64$

I do not understand the second line of the solution: why is the $\color{red}{red}$ sign negative, and not positive?

Comment: It's a typo.....

Comment: It’s just a typo. Note that the correct sign has reappeared in the next line.

Comment: It's helpful to cite the textbook (title, author, publication year) when asking about a possible erratum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red negative sign is a typo. It should be positive and the working will be correct.

Answer (score 3):

It was typo, but the red minus gives the same result: $$64\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-i\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{12}=64\left(\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)^{12}=$$
$$=64(\cos(-3\pi)+i\sin(-3\pi))=-64.$$

I think the following is a bit of better.
$$(1+i)^{12}=((1+i)^2)^6=(1+2i-1)^6=(2i)^6=-64.$$

Comment: The point is to exercise the use of de Moivre. This bypasses it.

Comment: @MPW See please better the question: "Confused about how to find the value of $(1+i)^{12}$"

Comment: And the more detailed description in the body of the question, including the answer from the text, suggests the problem is meant to exercise de Moivre

Comment: Also, even though the negative sign "works", how is it correct working? You're taking the power of another complex number here, such as $1-i$ rather than $1+i$.

Comment: @Deepak I added that it was typo. See please better my post.